# How can I import a SQL Server RDS backup into a SQL Server Linux Docker instance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-rds

I've followed the directions from the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html) on importing / exporting a database from RDS using their stored procedures.

The command was similar to:

```
exec msdb.dbo.rds_backup_database 
              @source_db_name='MyDatabase', 
              @s3_arn_to_backup_to='my-bucket/myBackup.bak'
```

This part works fine, and I've done it plenty of times in the past.

However what I want to achieve now; is restoring this database to a local SQL Server instance; however I'm struggling at this point. I'm assuming this isn't a "normal" SQL Server dump - but I'm unsure what the difference is.

I've spun up a new [SQL Server for Linux Docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-linux/) instance; which seems all set. I have made a few changes so that the `sqlcmd` tool is installed; so technically the image I'm running is comprised of this Dockerfile; not much different.

```
FROM microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y curl && \
    curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y mssql-tools unixodbc-dev
```

This image works fine; I'm building it via `docker build -t sql .` and running it via `docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=myPassword1!' -p 1433:1433 -v $(pwd):/backups sql`

Within my local folder, I have my backup from RDS downloaded, so this file is now in `/backups/myBackup.bak`

I now try to run `sqlcmd` to import the data with the following command; and I'm running into an issue which makes me assume this isn't a traditional SQL dump. Unsure what a traditional SQL dump looks like, but the majority of the file looks garbled with `^@^@^@^@` and of course other things.

```
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -i /backups/myBackup.bak -U sa -P myPassword1! -x
```

And finally; I get this error:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Syntax error at line 56048 near command 'GO' in file '/backups/myBackup.bak'.

**Final Answer**

My final solution for this mainly came from using `-Q` and running a `RESTORE` query rather than importing with the file, but I also needed to include some `MOVE` options as they were pointing at Windows file paths.

```
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -U SA -P myPassword -Q "RESTORE DATABASE MyDatabase FROM DISK = N'/path/to/my/file.bak' WITH MOVE 'mydatabase' TO '/var/opt/mssql/mydatabase.mdf', MOVE 'mydatabase_log' TO '/var/opt/mssql/mydatabase.ldf', REPLACE"
```

Comment: The `MOVE` option was key for me. I also needed to use the `FILELISTONLY` command beforehand to get the names I used with it.  W/o this I got errors about a files not being found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `RESTORE DATABASE` command to interact with your backup file instead of specifying it as an input file of commands to the database:

```
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P myPassword1! -Q "RESTORE DATABASE MyDatabase FROM DISK='/backups/myBackup.bak'"
```

[According to the sqlcmd Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017), the `-i` flag you used specifies:

> The file that contains a batch of SQL statements or stored procedures.

That flag likely won't work properly if given a database backup file as an argument.

Comment: This worked - thanks! Actually came across it a few hours later. I also needed to include statements like: `WITH MOVE 'xyz' TO '/var/opt/mssql/xyz.mdf'` since it was looking for Windows file paths. I'll update my question in full. Cheers